# Why trigger_dag not starting from failed task after restart in airflow?

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

Why trigger_dag command in cli is not starting from failed task after restart?

I'm using Triggerdanrunoperator to externally trigger the dag. While restarting, dagrun should run from where it is failed.

Any ways to accomplish? Kindly help.

Comment: If you want to rerun a failed task then you can `clear` it and the scheduler will continue from there.

Comment: 'Clear' will start from initial task not from failed one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the airflow clear command.

You can specify the --only_failed or the --task_regex with the --downstream flags.

Doco is here: 
https://airflow.apache.org/cli.html#clear

Comment: If task is successful but data processed was wrong. So i need to re-run again from that task. After clearing, task fails as "Run id triggered_tutorial2 : 2019-07-16T13:41:40.104592+00:00 already exists for dag id tutorial2".How to overcome this?